# Will SqlCeDataAdapter.RowUpdated event fire if the update wasn't from the instance which made it?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

Let's say I have two running instances of the same application and one of them has updated the database. if I have code registering for the SqlCeDataAdapter.RowUpdated event, will the event fire in the instance which did **not** make the update as well? Thanks.

**Edit: Anyone please? Thank you**

Comment: Isn't easiest to try and see what happens?

Comment: I've tried, worked on it for a long time and got into a few issues.

Comment: What does "into a few issues" mean?

Comment: a few more hours of work compared to getting a yes or no answer from someone who knows with benefit to the general public.